# Laravel lumen5.6(Integration of sql server in lumen 5.6)

Tags: php, laravel-5, lumen

I am working on lumen.I have made changes in .env file as below

```
 DB_CONNECTION=sqlsrv
    DB_HOST=TS1031
    DB_PORT=1433
    DB_DATABASE=dispensing
    DB_USERNAME=sa
    DB_PASSWORD=123
```

"
but it gives error

```
could not find driver (SQL: SELECT * from tbl_idssettings)
```

what i am doing wrong here?